# sqllite3 table not available even after comitting, Operational Error: no such table

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I created a test db as below, which works fine in the same python script.

```
import sqlite3 as db

conn = db.connect('test.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("drop table if exists temps")
cursor.execute('create table temps(date text, temp int)')
cursor.execute('insert into temps values("12/1/2011",35)')
cursor.execute('insert into temps values("13/1/2011",45)')
cursor.execute('insert into temps values("14/1/2011",42)')
cursor.execute('insert into temps values("15/1/2011",39)')
cursor.execute('insert into temps values("16/1/2011",41)')
conn.commit()

conn.row_factory = db.Row
cursor.execute('select * from temps')

rows= cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print ("%s %s" % (row[0], row[1]))

conn.close()
```

But When I access the same DB over a different script, I am able to open a connection but it shows error when I try to access the temps table.

```
import sqlite3 as db
conn = db.connect('test.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
conn.row_factory = db.Row
cursor.execute("select * from temps")
rows=cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print ("%s %s" % (row[0], row[1]))
```

Error:

```
    cursor.execute('select * from temps')
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: temps
```

Comment: Is the other script located in the same folder?

Comment: Thanks, it was in a different folder. But shouldn't sqlite act as a centre repository being able to access table from anywhere? I see two test.db created in two folders.

Comment: No, it has no central "server", basically it's started and stopped every time a python script is run. If just given a file name, it'll open or start a new database in the current directory, since it doesn't even have any idea that it has been run before.

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply the correct `path` to your database, the first script creates a database in the same folder as the one it is ran in.

For ease we will assume your first script is running in `C:\DataBase`, when it runs you will now see a file `test.db` in the `DataBase` folder. This file is your `sqlite3` database. To access this from another `python` script on the same machine you would need to:

```
import sqlite3 as db
conn = db.connect('C:\DataBase\test.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
conn.row_factory = db.Row
cursor.execute("select * from temps")
rows=cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print ("%s %s" % (row[0], row[1]))
```

Otherwise as you may have noticed the second script will just create a new database file `test.db` in the folder it was ran from.